# Is it possible to show power bi desktop app dashboard on dynamics 365?

Tags: powerbi, dynamics-crm, integration, dashboard

My question: I want to show my desktop Power BI app dashboard on Dynamics 365. Is it possible that we can integrate PBI desktop dashboard with Dynamics 365 and show the dashboard there?
Not asking for Sales analytics  or other app integration in dynamics.

This is blog which tell us about the data in dynamics but not with what created on Desktop app
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/dynamics-quick-create-report

I tried with Sales and other model driven app but the problem with those is been designed for particular structure of data. I'm expecting to achieve to show the dashboard that created on desktop app and share on dynamic 365 dashboard.